# How to find whether a page is redirecting or not?

Tags: java

I wanna know that how we can identify whether a page is redirecting to some other web page or not?

I'm using URLConnection class of java. 
One way that i know is, to check the headerfield 'Location' of the connection established.

But i'm not getting the solution :-(

Plz assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start using [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) and stop worrying about redirects.

Read [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/redirects.html) for more details.

Comment: I've used HttpClient but it's not working.
landing me to an error 'Connection to http://home.com refused'

I wanna check whether the page is redirecting to some other page or not.

Comment: I used that 'Location' header too.
Its value is NULL, showing that the page is not redirecting..

Answer (score 1):

Java HttpURLConnection follow redirects automatically, unless you call

```
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
```

try calling it before you open the url (you only need to do it once, it's a static function).

I am not sure if the Location header is respected by Java (it can be a browser only thing), but you should see an http response code of 301 or 302 (if I am not mistaken) which indicates a redirect in http level.